# NAnt <mail> task throwing Class not registered on command line

Tags: nant

This is my task

```
  <mail
  from="jenga_blocks@gmail.com"
  tolist="jenga_blocks@gmail.com"
  subject="${subject}${subject-suffix}"
  mailhost="mail.stg.ee.blabla.com"
  >

  <files>
    <include name="*txt"/>
  </files>
  <attachments>
    <include name="C:\Temp\*.jpg" />
  </attachments>  
  </mail>
```

This is failing with the following error

```
Error sending mail:
Error enountered while sending mail message.
Make sure that mailhost=mail.stg.ee.blabla.com

    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
        Class not registered
```

Seems to be interop issue , how do i solve it

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

- Anti-virus is not blocking nant.exe
- The mail service is running and listening on port 25
- You have permission to relay through the SMTP service
- The mail server host name can be successfully resolved to its IP

You can test with a local smtp service using [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com) for example.
Enable anonymous access and specify `mailhost="localhost"` and the email message should be displayed.  You may also want to temporarily disable your anti-virus and\or firewall during testing.

Comment: Well , actually lately I was experimenting with NUnit GUI and the same code works from inside the GUI , it fails only when I run it through the command line. I prefer command-line becaues that the way I am ultimately going to run test suites. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Is the GUI run with elevated permissions where as the command line is not?

Comment: command line uses .NET framework 4.0 where mail task fails. GUI uses .net framework 3.5 where it succeeds. How do i make Nant to pick 3.5?

Comment: Trying running nant.exe and passing "-t:net-3.5" without quotes on the command line.